# How to get the complete result of command "top -c -b -n 1" through java, Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)

Tags: java, linux, shell

I want to get the result of command "***top -c -b -n 1***" through java, ***Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)***,
but the COMMAND column of the process list was compressed like "/usr/lib/x+"! 
How to get the **complete** result like command executed directly on the linux terminal ?

Comment: You might find it easier to just read that sort of data from /proc

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with Java, it is a UNIX or top question. Does -w help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`top` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) mentions a `-w COLS` option to specify the number of columns it tries to format the output too:

```
$ top -c -b -n 1 -w 1000 | head -n10
top - 05:01:40 up 19 days, 13:29,  1 user,  load average: 1.62, 1.49, 1.43
Tasks: 287 total,   2 running, 285 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  7.5 us,  3.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 89.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 32771952 total,   742552 free,  9000236 used, 23029164 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 23029384 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 4227 qemu      20   0 10.628g 5.797g   4688 S 112.5 18.5  34262:17 /usr/libexec/qemu-kvm -name test-vm -S -machine pc-i440fx-rhel7.0.0,accel=kvm,usb=off -cpu Nehalem -m 6144 -realtime mlock=off -smp 3,sockets=3,cores=1,threads=1 -uuid A5A5DC7B-3F35-40F9-B799-954D5411A219 -nographic -no-user-config -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/test-vm.monitor,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=utc,driftfix=slew -global kvm-p+
  84 root      25   5       0      0      0 R  68.8  0.0  13144:24 [ksmd]
2834 andrew    20   0  130180   1888   1284 R   6.2  0.0   0:00.02 top -c -b -n 1 -w 1000
...
```

Now it’s cut off after about 500 characters, but hopefully that’s enough for what you’re doing.